# Networking unstable on iOS

Tags: codenameone

With CN1 on iOS, networking has become very unstable  lately. Simple HTTPS requests fail about 50% of the time, in an app that used to work smoothly. If I use two network threads (`updateNetworkThreadCount(2)`) and a standard network error listener, I get a message box with "There was a networking error in the connection to https://foo.bar". With only one network thread, the app hangs.

This problem occurs on both the two iPhones I've tested it on. Everything works fine in the simulator. I haven't tested this on Android yet.

This is an example of a failing network operation (it's the same for other HTTPS calls as well):

```
    private void doNetworkStuff() {
        ConnectionRequest req = new ConnectionRequest();
        req.setPost(false);
        req.setUrl("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json");
        req.addArgument("latlng", Double.toString(59) + "," + Double.toString(10));
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(req);
        byte[] data = req.getResponseData();

        try {
            String s = new String(data, "UTF8");
            ToastBar.showMessage(s, '0');
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ux) {
            ToastBar.showErrorMessage(ux.getMessage());
            Log.e(ux);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like the fix for this issue https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2357 triggered a regression

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed and we deployed a hotfix to resolve the regression. It should work now with new builds (and networking should be noticeably faster).